# Typescript: How to `apply` on a structure holding a record?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let says we have a Structure holding a record on which we wish to `apply` another Structure holding a Record holding functions for the keys of the first Structure. (basically the reverse of the `Apply` fantasy Land spec)

Let's first define some types we'll be using:

```js
type Index = string|number|symbol

type Struct<R extends Record<Index, any>> = {
  readonly value: R
  apOn: <B>(fab: Struct<{[K in keyof R]?: (a: R[K], k: K) => B}>) =>
    Struct<{[K in keyof R]: B}>
}
```

then tackles the structure itself

```js
declare function newStruct<R extends Record<Index, any>> (value: R): Struct<R>

const struct = newStruct ({a: 1, b: true})
```

The first two te works as expected when specifying for the `apOn` methods argument a `Struct` with same number of keys which have functions with same returns type.

```js
const withFuncsa = newStruct ({
  a: (a: number) => `${a}`,
  b: (a: boolean) => `${a}`,
})
const withFuncsb = newStruct ({
  a: (a: number) => a > 0,
})

const resa = struct.apOn (withFuncsa).value // as expected {a: string, b: string}
const resb = struct.apOn (withFuncsb).value // as expected {a: boolean, b: boolean}
```

But breaks when return types differs:

```js
const withFuncsc = newStruct ({
  a: (a: number) => a > 0,
  b: (a: boolean) => `${a}`,
})

const resc = struct.apOn (withFuncsc).value
// breaks cause expect all returns type of this withFuncc function to be identical
// expected {a: boolean, b: string}
```

Is they're a way to have it working with different return types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to rework the signature to defer deciding on `B` until the key it computes for is known.

```
type Struct<R extends Record<Index, any>> = {
  readonly value: R
  apOn: <F extends {[K in keyof Partial<R>]: (a: R[K], k: K) => any}>
      (fab: Struct<F>) =>  
          Struct<Omit<R, keyof F> & {[K in keyof F]: ReturnType<F[K]>}>
}
```

Here `F` is the mappers record. It is important that `[K in keyof Partial<R>]: ...` rather than `[K in keyof R]?: ...` because we want to ensure that the optional modifier isn't flattened to an `... | undefined`. The mappers are present and a function or not present.

Then in the return type we keep the unmapped fields the same `Omit<R, keyof F>` but for all mapped fields, take the type produced by the mapper, `{[K in keyof F]: ReturnType<F[K]>}`.

The intermediate types look a little messy in intellisense but they get the job done:

```
const t: {strings: string[], bools: boolean[]} = {
    strings: [resa.a, resa.b, resc.b],
    bools: [resb.a, resb.a, resc.a],
}
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDygXigZ2AJwJZwDmAPnAK4C2ARhDsZiNQPYA2AUG6JFAMq5kBjYAB4ASlBTAIiTFFEQBTHAmHwkyADRQAhnBAA+feigBvNlCg4I2hEzgsQUAG7aWZCAC455nWADycF7CAGISyFIypgDaANJQBFAA1hAgTABmUAAK2jjAeK5i+gC6XgAU2l6isUVaiV4xAJToRrogAL76PhYWpWnaVF58OIIiwfpNaEZQXd2zQyPCfhR4IqK1KelQY1AAZNFxCcmpGcElchDAZDhwACrgECHV+h1sbRxIAiw50GlkcEJ4OxQOAQADu8yEYjCEQQsnkimUqkQKC0rUMUFKLjcnjkDUG-Ehok6bEUcGwWAJwGMIPBlIxJgqUAAjFoBlB+BA2g0OKTyaCVgALYJ-ASYbTUsEQqmlMwWRnlLzkai0CZGAAGABIGW01RofGyFVAqExWNY4KqoJrtbrXtzeVT+cAhSLMFQJbThkJ6T55YylTQcBbxUYAAx6rk8uzkqxi4zYT3AAB02n8cAxjud-zFDUTWPcUAA9AWdLIUJAhBAEKZGfGCIRWV5a0Q3vbLBBXXHKcnU+nBcKs1Qc3noEWS2Fy1IqwyvMbTboG0aTSwzW8SVGHX2XQJ3VLvXKyn7KAGg1BQ3qLAbGbPl7oLVbtDrw9y12SqTHtxh4yNuwFe07+6KAhDq47iRq+7JeCYTaEJgja4HWUQ1IurCwchN5wIhbTGLK3TQahUQxtoyZaIRiZUCR7YCGRNQzNe+ExlQxFtq6THvsmNFtEAA)